# How is flutter sound stream representing pcm data?

Tags: flutter, audio, signal-processing, pcm

I need to make a app that visualizes audio data by graphing it, and I've tried [fluter sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) and [sound stream](http://47.240.41.80/packages/sound_stream) to get the raw audio data. However both of these libraries captures the sound as 16 bit pcm, but returns a stream of Uint8list. So I don't understand how they are representing the 16 bit pcm with 8 bit integers.

I've tried to just graph out the numbers as is, but it doesnt appear to be right. The following is the code I used to graph out 30hz sine wave, with the data sound_stream provides.

```dart
final Uint8List data; 
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) { 
    double dx = size.width / data.length;
    for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i+=1){
    canvas.drawLine(Offset((i - 1) * dx, (data[i-1].toDouble()/256) * size.height), Offset((i) * dx, (data[i].toDouble()/256) * size.height),  Paint()..color = Colors.red..strokeWidth=1);
    }
  }
```

[image: 30hz]

Comment: i've tried but the wave result not like this: https://fluttergems.dev/media-cards/flutter_audio_waveforms.png, any solution?

Comment: @mamenatech really depends on what you are trying to do, and what your code looks like. Care to share more? Or you can start a new stack overflow question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a `Uint8List` because that's a byte array and is what gets moved across the native-Dart boundary. So you need to view that byte array as a list of 16 bit integers. Use `ByteBuffer` to do this.

```
final Uint8List data;
final pcm16 = data.buffer.asInt16List();
// pcm16 is an Int16List and will be half the length of data
// expect values in pcm16 to be between -32768 and +32767 so
// normalize by dividing by 32768.0 to get -1.0 to +1.0
```

You will probably find that you are getting twice as many bytes as you expect. If you are sampling at 16kHz, expect 32k bytes a second, but you'll get 16000 samples a second when viewed as 16 bit ints.

Comment: thanks a lot, this exmplaination really helped.