# how to save wav from stream of audio data from bluetooth in Dart / flutter_blue

Tags: android, dart, audio, stream, bluetooth-lowenergy

im writing a simple FLutter/Dart app that get audio stream from BLE device ( `8Khz, 16Bit, Mono` ).. im using flutter_blue as the package to connect the BLE device

i have succeeded in subscribing the service and get the `List<int>` stream of data for the audio from the BLE devices. As per device's doc, it said the data is 8Khz, 16bit and Mono.

i refer to [Save audio stream / Uint8List data in file flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482473/save-audio-stream-uint8list-data-in-file-flutter) on how to save the data to WAV file and since the OP used the same kind of audio as me.

However, the file that i save sounds so noisy and makes no sense at all.. i did everything that i can think of:

- assuming the stream is 8bit int, so i convert to 16bit using Buffer ( refer : [How is flutter sound stream representing pcm data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71461611/how-is-flutter-sound-stream-representing-pcm-data) ) ( same result ).. confirmed converting is working when print() and the value is between 30000 something instead 255.
- refer to ( https://github.com/anarchuser/mic_stream/issues/9 ) since its like my problem but i cannot set my device to use 8bit encoding since its comes with 16bit encoding.

can someone guide me? im very new to flutter/dart and the syntax confuses me.. ( im coming from PHP )

Comment: i have succeeded in playing the sound using raw_sound packages.. it seems that sounds it self is noisy from the start and not because of wrong headers etc..